# Java type for AWS SNS message from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, spring-cloud-aws

I have a AWS SQS queue subscribed to a SNS topic. Message I receive from SQS queue looks like this:

```
Message body: {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "6ffbe51a-5c00-51f8-a67e-b468ad721131",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:447379608829:dev_com_pio_admin_package",
  "Message" : "CUSTOM_JSON_OBJECT",
  "Timestamp" : "2017-04-20T17:26:10.410Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "iLDcSwI5CJ.....==",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/...............",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/..............."
}
```

Is there a Java representing this kind of message in `Spring Cloud AWS` or in `AWS java SDK`?

Answer (score 0):

That is a json representation of the message.
The easiest way to convert that to a java object is probably [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping for an existing type from one of AWS frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation @NotificationMessage in Object (represent message) for listener.

Comment: @NotificationMessage returns  payload without metadata. I am asking also for metadata

Answer (score 0):

```
    @SqsListener("spring-boot-sqs")
public void getProductoFromSQS(String snsMessageJsonFormat) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SNSMessage snsMessage = gson.fromJson(snsMessageJsonFormat, SNSMessage.class);
    Producto producto = gson.fromJson(snsMessage.getMessage(), Producto.class);
    itemservice.save(producto);
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class SNSMessage {
    private String Type;
    private String MessageId;
    private String TopicArn;
    private String Message;

}
```

how you can see you need  to model Java Class SNSMessage

get the String Message and convert to appropriate Object with Gson. :)